# How to calculate the set complement operation in redis using redis ruby?

Tags: ruby, redis

For two sets in redis, there are operators to get a Union, Intersection, etc..

But I couldn't find any for the COMPLEMENT between 2 SETS?

Is there anyway that I missed to search/know on how to get a COMPLEMENT of SETS?

Example:

The redis example:

```
redis> SADD key1 "a"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key1 "b"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key1 "c"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key2 "c"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key2 "d"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key2 "e"
(integer) 1
redis> SDIFF key1 key2
1) "a"
2) "b"
redis>
```

The diff just gives back "a" and "b".

But I want "a", "b", "d" and "e" which is I think its the complement.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you want:

http://redis.io/commands/sdiff

Or, if you want to store the result:

http://redis.io/commands/sdiffstore

The ruby adapter follows the redis api quite strictly, so has the same commands.

**update:**

From the update i deduce you want the symmetric difference. You cannot do this in one operation, but you can do it in multiple:

```
redis> sdiffstore diff1 key1 key2 
redis> sdiffstore diff2 key2 key1
redis> sunion diff1 diff2
```

Comment: The comment box disables the code snippet. So, I've updated the question instead. Can you look at it once again?